# Добавление записей в БД

Tags: php, javascript

есть форма с 2 полями, которые после клика кнопки, нужно добавить в БД
Вот сама форма:

```
<form id="myform" action="buysell.php" method="post">
                                <div class="trading__buy-row">
                                    <div class="trading__buy-row-title">Price</div>
                                    <input type="text" id="price" name="price" onchange=f()>
                                    <div class="trading__buy-row-title2">111</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="trading__buy-row">
                                    <div class="trading__buy-row-title">Amount</div>
                                    <input type="text" id="amount" name="amount" onchange=f()>
                                    <div class="trading__buy-row-title2">111</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="trading__buy-row">
                                    <div class="trading__buy-row-title">Total</div>
                                    <input type="text" id="total" name="total" >
                                    <div class="trading__buy-row-title2">111</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="trading__buy-text">Trade commission: <span>0.1%</span></div>
                                <!--<div class="btn btn--buy" id="sub" >BUY </div> -->
                                <button id="sub">Buy</button>
                                <span id="result"></span>
                            </form>
```

Пхп файл:

```
    session_start();
    include_once('db.php');
    if(isset($_SESSION['userid'])){
    $sesion_id=$_SESSION['userid'];
    }
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $amount = $_POST['amount'];

    if($mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `ordersbuy` (`id`,`price`,`amount`) VALUES ('$sesion_id','$price','$amount')")){

      echo "Successfully Inserted";
    }
    else{
      echo "Insertion Failed";
    }
```

?>
И JS скрипт:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
$("#sub").click(function() {
$.post(
$("#myForm").attr(‘action’),
$("#myForm :input").serializeArray(),
function(info) {
$("#result").html(info)
}
);

clearInput();
});

$("#myForm").submit(function() {
return false;
});
});
```

Но после нажатия на кнопку никаких данных не добавляется, в чем дело?

Comment: `if(("INSERT INTO `ordersbuy` (`id`,`price`,`amount`) VALUES ('$sesion_id','$price','$amount')"))`
вы сформировали запрос, теперь нужно его запустить.
не значю что у вас там в db.php, но вот для начала http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Не заметил, исправил на  if($mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `ordersbuy` (`id`,`price`,`amount`) VALUES ('$sesion_id','$price','$amount')")) Но толку нет

Comment: Ответьте мне на вопрос: зачем столько дивов и непонятных действий. Постарайтесь упростить код по максимуму. из всех дивов не нужен ни 1. Есть тег form и ему сопустствующие их и пользуйте.

Comment: @Ljil Разве это как-то влияет на результат? Я про дивы

Comment: исправте сначала сам вопрос, потом в php файле проверьте происход ли к нему запрос. Например напишите там error_log('hello'); и смотрите логи во время запроса. Можете посмотреть в строну xdebug

Comment: @Midnight я про то, что от нагромождения дивов и кода в js - вам сложнее будет понять где что не работает. Отследить 1 действие в 1 месте проще, чем 40 действий в 40 местах.

Comment: @Ljil поправил вопрос, проблема была в кнопке, теперь перебрасывает на страницу buysell.phр и там выводит Successfully Inserted, но цель сделать все без перезагрузки

Comment: @Midnight без предзагрузки используется AJAX. На кнопку вешаете вызов функции, который собирает данные с полей и отправляет и в методе success будет очищать форму.

Comment: @Ljil так вроде как раз в JS скрипте я это и делаю

Comment: забываете сделать `preventDefault()`